# IN VBA is it possible to get the recall message target?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Using the mail object properties I can get information about a recall message, but I don't know how to grab the information about the message it is going to remove.

The body gives the subject, but the emails being recalled in my case are not unique in sender nor in subject and so a combination of values for the target message are needed to unique them.

Thanks for your help and time,
Outis

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458(v=office.15).aspx) property values to identify their items uniquely. Here is what MSDN states:

> A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for an Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved.

Also you may consider adding your own ID as a [user property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869073(v=office.15).aspx).